# Kernel Dimensions returned as long and not integer

Tags: python, numpy

Why when I inspect my array dimensions does it say its `[3L,3L]`? Why not just `[3,3]`? This affects my ability to access an element in the array because I pass a float not an integer.

See below for my example:

```
kernel_x = [
    [ -1, 0, 1 ],
    [ -2, 0, 2 ],
    [ -1, 0, 1 ]
]

kernel_x_mat = np.array(kernel_x)

dim = kernel_x_mat.shape
print dim # [3L,3L]

# The long causes an error because I get
# floats from ::shape
# Ie, this is invalid...
src[r,c] = kernel_x_mat[dim[0]-1, dim[1]-1]
# dim[0]-1 = 2.0 not 2 which causes an error
```

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior on python 2.7 (or 3.5 for that matter).  `print(type(dim[0]-1))` gives `<class 'int'>`  What versions are you using?

Comment: On 64-bit Windows with Python 2.7, Python `ints` are 32-bit (to match the C `long` type), but `ndarray` dimensions can be 64-bit, so a Python `long` is returned. Not sure how the conversion to a `float` happens. That ought not to happen in this code snippet.